Does DataReader of ADO.NET Interact with the SQL Server For Every Row it fetches or Does it maintain a cache or buffer?
I've used datareader for reading data from SQL Server. Now let us say I've 20 rows in the table. So does my ADO.NET make 20 interactions with the SQL Server to fetch the data or does it  bring all the data in a single go and store it in my local computer cache?
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(stmt, instance))
            {
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                      while (reader.Read())
                      {
                              //perform operations
                      }
                }
            }

All these confusion arose as, when you close the connection while the "while(reader.Read())" we will get an exception. So my understanding was it interacts with the server 20 times but it is a big toll on performance. So I assumed maybe ADO.NET uses stores all those 20 rows in local computer cache and reads it from there row by row. If this is the case why does it throw an exception when we close the connection?

Does this answer your question? How DataReader works?

I haven't checked the code, but my understanding is "somewhere in the middle"; the client can store some unprocessed data in local memory, and read more chunks of data (that are already probably en-route) when the existing data has been consumed; it doesn't need to fetch "all the data in a single go", nor does it need to fetch data row by row - in fact, in some cases (large BLOB/CLOB data), there could be multiple reads for a single row

Should be still valid: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms187602(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN ("SQL Server puts as many result set rows as possible in each packet.")

Let's say you get your answer, does it matter for the task you have at hand? Either way, someone will fetch rows from TDS, either up-front or when you do your Read(). What's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

I am new to ADO.NET, and I wanted to understand the internal workings of the DataReader. So that, if possible, I can make my application more performance-oriented by reducing the stress on the network and the server.

Not sure how you're gonna do that, you either fetch or not fetch data i guess :) Unless you want to implement your own version of DataReader i say just keep using the one provided

SqlClient (both the old System.Data and the new Microsoft.Data) uses the TDS protocol.
The TDS protocol works in "messages", "tokens" and "packets", and the client-side logic generally processes these sequentially (ie pulling in the next packet one at a time). Server and client communicate using messages (which may or may not contain token streams), and these are split up into packets for the physical transmission.
There are many types of messages, but the Row Data message is a token stream, made up of the column definitions tokens, followed by the actual row data tokens. This data may (and usually does) span multiple packets. The actual rows are not necessarily one per packet, they can overlap or be multiple in a single packet.
As far as I am aware, there is no further buffering inside of SqlDataReader, except that it always buffers a full row (unless you use CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess in which case it doesn't even do that). The source code is here.
Since it's all done over TCP, there are also often intermediate buffers, whether in usermode (your app), the kernel/drivers, and the network card itself, and possibly even switches and routers along the way.

Yeah... it's not so much it doesn't buffer, as it lets the network environment determine what buffering will be effective ;) ... with the caveat this often means buffering happens at unusual boundaries that don't line up with specific rows or even columns, but c'est la vie

If network latency is your concern, the best solution is to use a "client side cursor". *(Which is a term that comes from ADO).

use a SqlDataAdpter to run the query
Ask the DataAdapater to dump the results into a DataSet
Use dataset.CreateDataReader() to get your standard IDataReader

Full example here

But if the size of the results is more than the space left in your local memory...then would that be an issue?

It absolutely would be an issue for a 32-bit application; where you are limited to 2 GB of memory.
